# Gradle Task dependencies Execution issue

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am facing an issue related to gradle task dependencies. One of my gradle task is calling another task successfully but it is not executing dependencies on which my second task depends. Please go through the following code to understand the problem statement:

My code is:

```
task callGradleDeploy <<{
   tasks.deployComp.execute()
}

task deployComp (dependsOn: ['setEnvParameter', 'installWeb', 'installService']) <<{
   println "Deployment Done"
}
task setEnvParameter {
  //parameter Setting for deployement
}
task installWeb {
  //install Web Code
}
task installService {
  //install Services Code
}
```

Now when I run task **callGradleDeploy**, it is calling **deployComp** task but it is not installing Web or Service content (Not doing anything with ***setEnvParameter, installWeb, installService*** ). and Just printing *Deployment Done*

Just to notify, when I am individually calling(running) ***deployComp*** task, it is installing Web and Service part without any issue.

Please help me to understand how to manage this **dependsOn** thing while calling a gradle task into another.

***Second part:***

***//*******************  Edited part below, For clear understanding   *****************//***

@Opal I have done configuration like below after your suggestion.

*For the cases, where only deployService should work. It is still calling deployWeb and deployWebAndService both.*

Code is here:

```
task deploy (dependsOn : ['deployWeb', 'deployService', 'deployWebAndService']) <<{
    println "\n\tExecuting respective task"
}

task deployWeb (dependsOn : ['configureWebApp','stopWebApp','uninstallWebApp','installWebApp','startWebApp']) <<{
        println "\n\tExecuting deploy for Web Content"
}
task deployService (dependsOn : ['configureService','stopService','uninstallService','installService','startService']) <<{
        println "\n\tExecuting deploy for Service Content"
}
task deployWebAndService (dependsOn : ['configureWebApp','configureService','stopWebApp','uninstallWebApp','installWebApp','startWebApp','stopService','uninstallService','installService'/*,'startService'*/]) <<{
        println "\n\tExecuting deploy for Web and Service Content"
}


deployWeb.onlyIf{
    (WebContent.equals("Yes") && ServiceContent.equals("No"))   //fetching "Yes"/"No" values from a separate function
}
deployService.onlyIf{
     (WebContent.equals("No") && ServiceContent.equals("Yes"))
}
deployWebAndService.onlyIf{
     (WebContent.equals("Yes") && ServiceContent.equals("Yes"))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Your `build.gradle` should look as follows:

```
task callGradleDeploy(dependsOn: ['deployComp']) {

}

task deployComp (dependsOn: ['setEnvParameter', 'installWeb', 'installService']) <<{
   println "Deployment Done"
}

task setEnvParameter{
  //parameter Setting for deployement
}

task installWeb{
  //install Web Code
}

task installService{
  //install Services Code
}
```

First of all you should never call task's `execute()` method manually, since this highly discouraged and interferes gradle's internal logic (directed acyclic graph). To define dependencies between tasks the following methods should be used:

- [`mustRunAfter`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#mustRunAfter(java.lang.Object...))
- [`shouldRunAfter`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#shouldRunAfter(java.lang.Object...))
- [`dependsOn`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#dependsOn(java.lang.Object...))

In your particular case it's enough to substitute `execute` invocation with `dependsOn` and it works perfectly. Also please note the `<<` to indicate action is deprecated and scheduled to be removed in version 5.0. Instead use `doLast`:

```
task callGradleDeploy {
   doLast { println 'action' }
}
```

**EDIT**

See the solution below. The advantage is that you configure dependencies between tasks once. To check if it works correctly run `gradle deploy -Pwc` or `gradle deploy -Psc`

```
task explodeWarContent {
  doLast {
    println 'Code to explode war'
  }
}

task configureWebApp(dependsOn: explodeWarContent) {
  doLast {
    println 'Code to configure web app'
  }
}

task stopWebApp {
  doLast {
    println 'Code to stop web app'
  }
}

task uninstallWebApp(dependsOn: stopWebApp) {
  doLast {
    println 'Code to uninstall web app'
  }
}

task installWebApp(dependsOn: configureWebApp) {
  mustRunAfter uninstallWebApp
  doLast {
    println 'Code to install web app'
  }
}

task startWebApp(dependsOn: installWebApp) {
  mustRunAfter stopWebApp
  doLast {
    println 'Code to start web app'
  }
}

task deployWebApp(dependsOn: [uninstallWebApp, startWebApp]) {
  onlyIf { project.hasProperty('wc')}
}

task configureService {
  doLast {
    println 'Code to configure service'
  }
}

task stopService {
  doLast {
    println 'Code to stop service'
  }
}

task uninstallService(dependsOn: stopService) {
  doLast {
    println 'Code to uninstall service'
  }
}

task installService(dependsOn: configureService) {
  mustRunAfter uninstallService
  doLast {
    println 'Code to install service'
  }
}

task startService(dependsOn: installService) {
  mustRunAfter stopService
  doLast {
    println 'Code to start service'
  }
}

task deployService(dependsOn: [uninstallService, startService]) {
  onlyIf { project.hasProperty('sc')}
}

task deploy {
  dependsOn deployWebApp, deployService
}
```

Comment: I thought in this way, but the thing is I have 3 deployComp tasks which are independent and I need to call them all in callGradleDeploy task on condition basis. means if only Condition1 then deployComp1, if only Condition2 then deployComp2.. kind of..

Comment: @VinayVerma then define the dependencies and use [`onlyIf`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#onlyIf(groovy.lang.Closure)) to set particular task to run or not.

Comment: Ok I will try this way. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Opal whatever I have done, I edited in my question only. Please have a look in the second part of it

Comment: @VinayVerma could you please prepare a minimal runnable example that shows the problem? Currently many tasks remain undefined which makes it hard to reproduce.

Comment: You can refer the second part only. which I have added just now.

Comment: @VinayVerma, yes I know but still the example you provided is not runnable, e.g. some tasks are not defined as well as `WebContent` - how can I help you if I even can't reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please check the code [here](https://github.com/vinay1591/Examples/blob/a64a67b33251740bf9ba5b9e1b21faa04e34260a/gradle_dependency_issue.txt)

Comment: I finally got the solution of the problem I was facing. [This](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/need-help-in-gradle-task-and-depends-on-example/22580/7?u=vinay_a_verma) solution worked for me

Comment: @VinayVerma, cool, glad that you've it worked out. I'll try to have a look later on and edit the answer as well.